# It should be safe to delete bin and object folders?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I have a solution, that I took a backup before I started messing around.

Then I deleted the bin and object folder.

When I build, it created new bin and object folders, but when I run it, I get an 401.2 error.

If I copy over the bin and object folders from the backup it works again.

If I do a clear, it still Works.

If I delete the two folders and visual studio recreates them I get a 401.2 again

This makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: Maybe permissions?

Comment: If you delete the two folders and access the server using your browser's private browsing mode, is there any issue? I'm guessing there's some session stuff you're storing in `bin` that is getting wiped.

Comment: Llama, thanks I will try this monday, I know another developer have been working with saving the session in Redis, perhaps there is some stuff he needs to clean up from working with sessions.

Comment: Yes, you can delete bin and obj without any problem. Unless you put by hand or let drag files and dlls, for example old nugets or whatever custom. Next use Rebuild. Compare with backup to see difference in case of problem, and identidy missing files.

Answer (score 0):

As pr Olivier Rogiers suggestion, I did a comparison between the created bin folder and the backup. It turned out that "microsoft.owin.host.systemweb.dll" was not copied out to local despite being marked as to be copied out.
I removed the checkmark, rebuild, put the checkmark back, rebuilt, but to no avail.

Now at least I know the reason, now I just need to figure out why.

Answer (score -2):

please remove old project from solution in order to build it successfully [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mon1a.png)
look to image for more explanation. assume that I delete data project from solution without remove it from solution if I build it and run it i will get error so I have to remove it from sln